Space after \euro
I would like to use \euro but there is no space after the euro symbol and the following word. Am I doing something wrong or can this problem be solved?
    \documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,titlepage]{jurabook}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english,ngerman]{betababel}
    \usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets, maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
    \usepackage[
      style     = jura2,
      backend   = biber,
      sorting   = nty,
      sortcites = true,
      maxnames  = 4,
      minnames  = 4,
      articlein = false,
      date      = comp,%short
      urldate   = comp,
      dateabbrev = true,
      useprefix = true,
      isbn      = false,
      doi       = true,
      idemtracker=constrict,
      backref   = false,
      abbreviate = true,
    ]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\begin{document}

Pay me 10 \euro at the end of the month.

\end{document}


Try Pay me 10 \euro\ at the end of the month.

Perfect! It worked! Thank you so much for your quick reply. Just as a footnote: The 'strange' thing is, that it works perfectly find we I use it like this I received money (10 \euro) when I worked. So after the parenthesis there is space.

You can also use \euro{}. Why is this? See this Q&A.
